# Why delete messages in discord.net crashes

Tags: c#, crash, discord, bots, discord.net

Unfortunately I have a problem with the discord.net libraries. basically when I try to delete a message from the 'message_receive_event' event by doing `message.DeleteAsync()` Discord outputs this error message `Log: 18:40:16 Gateway     A MessageReceived handler has thrown an unhandled exception.: Discord.Net.HttpException: The server responded with error 403: Forbidden in Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()`. I have already tried several times a solution among the many forums and documents of discord.net, but nobody seems to have encountered a problem like mine. If you need to watch the code to solve the problem: https://github.com/carpall/dalvikbot

Comment: `403: Forbidden` - The bot does not have permission to delete the message.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  the detail really blew me away

Answer (score 0):

As said by Anu6is, the bot does not have permissions to delete the message. When your bot joined your server it gave it a role that is named after your bots name. Make sure to go into your role settings and give it administrator perms. I am kinda late but hoping I can help the people who search for the same issue in the future.